# Blender 2.6: How to undo 3D cursor movement

Tags: graphics, 3d, blender

hi, my mouse is very sensitive, and that's why I sometimes place the 3D cursor on the wrong location by a undesigned left click.

But when I'm trying to click `Control + Z` in order to undo the accidental 3D cursor movement, it doesn't revert.

So **my question** is: Is there an easy way to get Blender's (2.6) 3D cursor back to it's *previous* location? Thanks.

Comment: fridojet - Stackoverflow is not the correct site to post questions about Blender. I suggest you go to their forums (http://www.blender.org/community/user-community/)  or ask the question in the Blender subforum at cgsociety.org (http://forums.cgsociety.org/). Good luck.

Comment: You might also have luck at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thought about turning your mouse sensitivity down?

Comment: @cbamber85 I'm not talking about the /movement/ sensitivity - I'm talking about the mouse button's /click/ sensitivity. Anyway, thanks for your tip! ...

Comment: @libertas Yeah, here's my [gamedev question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31354/blender-2-6-how-to-undo-3d-cursor-movement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@libertas advised me to post this question on GameDev, so there I got a really [helpfull answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/31357/17554) (Thanks to @Byte56 !)

Answer (score 1):

**Shift - C** moves the cursor to (0,0,0)

Another way is switch to "Edit Mode" and select an edge. Then press **Shift - S** and select "**Cursor to selected**".